# Multi layer perceptron implementation on pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

please help me to solve out this error MLP on PYtorch
Neural network def

```py
# Hyper-parameters 
input_size = 48 
hidden_size = 16
num_classes = 4
num_epochs = 2
batch_size = 15
learning_rate = 0.001

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        #self.input_size = input_size
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size*input_size, input_size) 
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)  
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes) 
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.l1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.l2(x))
        out = self.l3(out)
model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes)
print(model)

#model training
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate) 
# Train the model
n_total_steps = len(trainloader)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (features, labels) in enumerate(trainloader):  
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        #features = batch[0].reshape(1,48*48).to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        
        # Forward pass
        outputs =  model.to(features)
        print(outputs)
        loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(outputs, labels)
        loss = torch.criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
            print (f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Step [{i+1}/{n_total_steps}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')
```

```py
TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not NeuralNet
```

please help me to solve out this error

Comment: Error at loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(outputs, labels)

Comment: You are not using the forward method of your NeuralNetwork, why is there a .to in that line?

Comment: I have remove .to from outputs =  model.to(features) it is giving me this error  RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x48 and 2304x48)
My tabular data set size is 48 column(features) 6146 rows 
how to set the input_size, hidden_size parameter of neural network.
please help ASAP

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove `.to(features)` with `model(features)`. Also, your input size and the last dimension of the `features` tensor should be the same. Based on your comment, you passed a 1*48 tensor to your network, so the input size of your first linear layer should be 48.

You can provide the shape of your data in your question in case your problem is not solved.

Based on your comments, your NeuralNet class should be like this.

```
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        #self.input_size = input_size
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size*2) 
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, hidden_size)  
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes) 
        
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu1(self.l1(x))
        x = self.relu2(self.l2(x))
        out = self.l3(x)
```

Comment: My features size are torch.Size([1, 48])

Comment: Based on that, your code should like ```self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size,  ... )```

Comment: Now i am getting this error at " loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(outputs, labels)"

TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not NoneType

Comment: I edit my answer with the code, so you can use that instead of your NeuralNet class

Comment: now i am getting this error
TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not NoneType

Comment: What are the outputs of your model after feeding them with your tensor?